# Create model in laravel with relations

Tags: mysql, laravel, model

**How to create Models from database with relations in Laravel 5.x?**

I am using this command to create models but it is showing any relationship which is in database schema:

```
Artisan::call('make:model', array("name"=>'Modules/Admin/Models/Campaign'));
```

Comment: you have to define your relationships yourself :)

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2017/episodes/7

Comment: I think there should be some way around as there can be a large database with lots of relations.

Answer (score 1):

You have to defince your relationships yourself, laravel can't do that for u.

```
public function relation1()
{
   $this->hasMany('CLASS_NAME', 'FK');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that we have a  store which includes many different products of brands.So in this case, I need to create one to many relation because, every brand has many products and very product has only one brand.So let's create our models by using artisan command.

```
  php artisan make:model Product -m  //  "-m" creates tables for us. 
  php artisan make:model Brand -m
```

so let's create the relationship ;

In "Product" model I am creating brand function  for relation

```
   public function brand (){

        $this->belongsTo('App\Brand')  ;
  }
```

to make understating of this      statemet  clear, read it like this. "Product belongsTo, Brand" if it's  logically correct than you are in right path.

Same logic is valid for reverse relation but this time you  cannot use belongsTo because it's already used, so it is more logical to use "has many"
       In "Brand" model I am creating brand function  for relation

```
   public function products(){

        $this->hasmany('App\Product')  ;
  }
```

read it as , "Brand has many Product".

Comment: Yes what you wrote here is write , but now I have database of more than 200 tables containing many more relations. Now how can I get the relations of one to one or if it is one to many or some thing else in each model ? Is there any way in Laravel which will add these relations in the models ? Like in Hibernate (JAVA ) while creating classes from database it generates these relationships automatically.